# Show that the inner product of the Legendre polynomials and $p\in L^2 ([-1,1])$ is equal to zero if the polynomial has degrees less than $n$

Tags: fourier-series, inner-products, legendre-polynomials

Let $(P_n )^{\infty}_{n=0}$ be the Legendre polynomials in $L^2([-1,1])$, normalised as $||P_n||^2=\frac{2}{2n+1}$.

I need to show that, for any polynomial $p\in L^2([-1,1])$ with degree less than $n$, we have $<P_n ,p>=0$, but I have no idea where to start with it (I would not like a full answer, but would appreciate a point in the right direction).

Comment: To prove that the inner product is zero for any polynomial, show that it is zero for the mimic polynomials $p_k(x)= x^k$. To do so, use induction on $n$ and the recurrence relation for the for the Legendre polynomials.

Comment: @User8128 What is a mimic polynomial ?

Comment: Sorry, autocorrect: “monic” polynomial